# Chromeのwebドライバーについて

Tags: python

pythonで自動ログインしようとしているんですが、一番最初にChromeのwebドライバーを使ってchromeを立ち上げるところにつまづいています。実装はgoogleコラボで行っています。osはwindows10です。chromeのバージョンは98.0.4758.82ですが、ダウンロードページにはピッタリのバージョンがないため、98.0.4758.80ものをダウンロードしました。コード書き方やexeファイルの配置場所変更を試したんですが、エラーを解消することができませんでした。どうすればよろしいでしょうか

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

# ここでエラー
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/content/drive/MyDrive/chromedriver.exe")
```

エラー

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stdin=PIPE,
---> 76                                             creationflags=self.creationflags)
     77         except TypeError:

5 frames
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/drive/MyDrive/chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     86                 raise WebDriverException(
     87                     "'%s' executable may have wrong permissions. %s" % (
---> 88                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     89                 )
     90             else:

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Comment: 質問に書かれていることがチグハグで整合性が取れていないようです。「実装はgoogleコラボで行っています。osはwindows10です。」と書かれていますが、Windows10に関係するのは実行ファイル名`chromedriver.exe`だけで、質問時の抽象化(情報隠し)のための書き変えでなければ、そのフォルダーパス`"/content/drive/MyDrive/chromedriver.exe"`やseleniumのパス`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py`はWindows10のものでは無いような感じです。Windows10でのエラーならばこんな質問のエラーメッセージになるはずでは？ [windows10 権限について　selenium chromedriver](https://teratail.com/questions/169425) だからGoogle Colaboratoryでそのまま実行しているのでは無いですか？ 内容を見直してみてください。

Comment: すみません、Google Colaboratoryでそのまま実行しています。exeファイルをアップロードし、パスを指定してあげれば実行できると思ったのですが、実際は無理なんですかね

Comment: Google ColaboratoryのOSはUbuntuなのでWindows10の実行ファイルは動作しません。[【Google Colab】OS、GPUのバージョン確認方法と現在のバージョン(2021年12月)](https://wasurenamemo.blogspot.com/2020/09/google-colabosgpu.html) Linux用のChromedriverを使いましょう。またエラーメッセージにもあるように、実行ファイルとしてのパーミッションを設定しておく必要があるでしょう。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

Google Colaboratoryで動作させるのなら、その環境であるUbuntuでのChromeDriverをインストールして使う必要があるでしょう。

この辺の記事で方法が示されています。
[【Python】Google ColaboratoryでSelenium実行](https://yuyuublog.com/colaboratoryselenium/)
[Google Colaboratoryでwebスクレイピング](https://kimudiary.com/colab/google-colaboratory%e3%81%a7web%e3%82%b9%e3%82%af%e3%83%ac%e3%82%a4%e3%83%94%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0-2/)
[GoogleColaboratoryでchromedriverを利用する(2021年9月版)](https://i-doctor.sakura.ne.jp/font/?p=46745)

いずれも基本は以下コマンドでChromeDriverをインストールすることらしいですね。
これでインストールすればパーミッションも自動的に設定されるのでしょう。

```
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

上記の中にはその前にパッケージ情報を更新したり、インストールされたChromeDriverをコピーしたりする作業を書いた記事もありますが、必要なら行えば良いのでは？

Comment: 記事やコマンドまで詳細に書いていただき、ありがとうございます。